# MySQL doesn't perform UPDATE correctly with smaller values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to update a few entries in a database and it works perfectly for values like 70000 or 90000, but when I try it with 3000 or so, it just doesn't do anything. I tried to enter the directly into the SQL console but it doesn't work either.

That's the code:

```
$query = "UPDATE `leaderboard` SET `leaderkills` = $totalkills WHERE `steamid` = $steamid";
```

I printed out the query and it works with this one:

```
UPDATE `leaderboard` SET `leaderkills` = 93709 WHERE `steamid` = 76561198036906035
```

but not with this one:

```
UPDATE `leaderboard` SET `leaderkills` = 2859 WHERE `steamid` = 76561198005842077
```

I've also made a screenshot of my table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyN3u.png).

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should seriously consider changing your `varchar` field from steamid to something else like the others. `bigint`should work just fine for it.

Comment: did you check  if there are records with leaderkills=2859? You've changing BOTH of the values in the two queries.

Comment: What are the values ? And why are you using `double` for what looks like an integer ?

Comment: What's the number of affected rows here? Also, you don't seem to be [properly escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) values like `$totalkills` or `$steamid`.

Comment: @tadman I am escaping them, it's data I directly get from an API, the affected rows are all of them.

Comment: The biggest problem with `mysql_query` is those values don't look escaped, and *might* not be. If you miss even one your application can be cracked wide open. This is why it's strongly recommended to use a database driver that supports placeholder values like `?` or `:steamid` to avoid confusion and make it absolutely certain they are escaped.

Comment: @dystroy That seems to have fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

steamid = 76561198005842077 exist in your table?

76561198036906035 != 76561198005842077

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the possible problems can be the fact that steamid is a varchar while you're passing it as integer, try to enclose it in quotes in your query:

```
UPDATE `leaderboard` SET `leaderkills` = 2859 WHERE `steamid` = "76561198005842077"
```

apart from that, as someone suggested steamid should be an integer

Comment: steamid is a varchar(30), so ' quotes should be fine. Assuming that steamid with that value exists already, leaderkills is a _double_ -- can it have a fractional value? 2859 should normally be acceptable as a double, but perhaps the database does something freaky with that declaration. If leaderkills can only have integer values, I would suggest a 32 or 64 bit integer as the field type. A double only has 16 or so digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Without having all the values it's hard to be sure but the problem here might be that you're using a non precise number type (`double`) to hold what could be precisely stored in an [integer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) column.